# How do I make the area outside of round button not clickable in javafx

Tags: javafx

When I make a round Button like this

```
Button b = new Button();
b.setShape(new Circle(20.0));
b.setText("BUTTON");
b.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 50em; " +
           "-fx-min-width: 50px; " +
           "-fx-min-height: 50px; ");
```

It can be still clicked in area outside of circle like the one I marked red here:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Button has the `pickOnBounds` property, Defines how the picking computation is done for this node when triggered by a MouseEvent or a contains function call.
You need to set `pickOnBounds` property to `false`

`pickOnBounds` doesn't seem settable from CSS, meaning you'll need to set it from code

`b.pickOnBoundsProperty().setValue(false);`

Comment: Using `b.setPickOnBounds(false)` would be more idiomatic.